# Order IEnumerable without LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.0

Can you advice any solution of how to sort `IEnumerable<byte> indexes` in .NET 3.0 (no LINQ)?
Of course it is possible to determine `indexes` length, create array, copy element-by-element, then call `Array.Sort(array)`. But may be can you suggest anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you aren't using the 2.0 compiler (so: VS 2008 / 2010 / 2012), you can use [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/downloads/list), and use LINQ-to-Objects from your .NET 2.0/3.0 code.

The other lazy solution is:

```
List<byte> list = new List<byte>(indexes);
list.Sort();
// list is now a sorted clone of the data
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is any other solution then iterating over "manually", in `C# 2.0`

Another option of creating array.

You can create a `List<>`

```
var list = new List<byte>(indexes ); 
list.Sort(delegate(byte b1, byte b2)
{
      //your comparison logic here
});
```

It's more compact then simple `for` or `foreach` iteration over collection.

Answer (score 1):

The entire `IEnumerable<>` has to be read when you sort it, so there is no way around that. Even the Linq to Objects method `Sort` keeps the entire collection in memory.

Create a `List<byte>` from the `IEnumerable<byte>` and sort it:

```
List<byte> list = new List<byte>(indexes);
list.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't really change an IEnumerable, you're going to have to copy the data somewhere else to sort it.

However, note you're sorting bytes, you can use [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) for ultra-efficient sorting.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80546/Comparison-Sorting-Algorithms-in-C-Explained

This came in handy when i was on a search for a solution